# How to limit power to multiple gpu's?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, power-management

I currently have 3 graphics cards **1 rtx3060ti** and **2 rtx3080ti**. One **rtx3060ti** is currently up and mining and I reduced it power consumption down from **200watts** to **140watts** using the command

`sudo nvidia-smi -pl 140`

in CLI. But now that i also want to mine on **rtx3080ti's**, I want to reduce **rtx3080ti's** power consumption down. So what do i need to do to get its power consumption down without affecting the power consumption of **rtx3060ti**.

I have install
`sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-470 nvidia-smi`

I m using ubuntu 20.04LTS.

I have also changed the
`sudo nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=28`

Is it possible to:-

`sudo nvidia-smi -pl 140 300 300`

To reduce the power of **rtx3060ti to 140, rtx 3080ti to 300 and rtx 3080ti to 300?**

Answer (score 1):

The nvidia-smi `-i` option should allow you to select an individual gpu to modify.  This option will accept the the gpu index, serial number, UUID, or PCI bus ID.